# MS SQL 2008 - Iterate and replace everything between two characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having trouble iterating and replacing everything between two characters in a string using MS SQL 2008 R2.

I'm currently trying to pull out everything between the ^ and ~ characters. I'm using the following SQL:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(255) = '0123^Hello~456^Filler Text~789^Even more filler text~'

SELECT STUFF(@string, PATINDEX('%^%',@string), PATINDEX('%~%',@string)+1 - PATINDEX('%^%',@string), replace(replace(@string, '^', ''), '~', ''))
```

I want the output to be "Hello Filler Text Even more filler text". Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Although you could write a function to do this, SQL Server is not the best tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

As your Output looks like reading only Alpha Values from `Sting` then you could try below `SQL` Command :

```
DECLARE @str NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @counter INT;
SET @str = '0123^Hello~456^Filler Text~789^Even more filler text~';
SET @counter = 0;
WHILE @counter <= 57
    BEGIN
        SET @str = REPLACE(@str, CHAR(0+@counter), ' ');
        SET @counter = @counter + 1;
    END;
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(@str, '^', ''), '~', '')));
```

**Output :**

```
Hello   Filler Text   Even more filler text
```